# Using regular expressions with BeautifulSoup's select_one

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have read answers on this website that describe using reg ex for 'find' queries in BeautifulSoup. However answers are less clear regarding the use of reg ex and querying on multiple tags while using 'select_one'.

Specifically I have two tags, shown below.

```
'#CommitYear14'
'#CommitYear12'
```

So I just need a query that looks for matches with '#CommitYear'.

My query right now is

```
college_info = beautiful_soup_parsing.select_one(tag)
```

where tag is either '#CommitYear14' or '#CommitYear12'. I don't know how to get both 14 and 12.

Comment: can you provide your html you are after?

Comment: can both be present on a given page or only one?

Answer (score 0):

Function `select_one()` is for applying CSS selectors, you cannot use `re` with it. But however, you can use CSS selecor `^=` which selects element(s) whose attribute value begins with selected string (for reference on CSS selectors [look at this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)):

```
data = '''
<div id="CommitYear12">CommitYear12</div>
<div id="CommitYear14">CommitYear14</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('[id^="CommitYear"]'))
```

Prints:

```
<div id="CommitYear12">CommitYear12</div>
```